# How to concatenate a cell array (15 cells in an array, each are around 1x7500)

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation, cells

This is probably one of this simplest questions, so it's likely been asked already, but I couldn't find any questions that were as simple as this one (they were all more complicated issues dealing with concatenation).

I have cell array with 15 cells.  Each cell is a single row vector with around 7500 values or columns, hence them being 1x7500 or so.

I want to concatenate those 15 cells in the array into a single vector.  The resulting vector will be around 1x112500 (I just want to piece the ends of the cells together). I don't think horzcat is helping, since horzcat(myarray) just makes an identical cell array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you expand your cell doing `myCell{:}`, this will create a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) from your cell contents. Afterwards you merge them using brakets `[myCell{:}]` if you want to merge   as a line vector. I think this is the easiest way of doing what you want…

```
>> myCell = {[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8]}

>> [myCell{:}]    

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

Another alternative is [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
>> cell2mat(myCell)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: cell2mat was the simplest.  Thanks so much!!